# How can I have my scanner skip over the "ADD_Airport" string?

Tags: java, file

I am reading these from a file and need to store the information in arrays to print them into another file. One for the three-letter code, one for the city name, and one for the letters at the end. The problem I'm having is that when I want to read them, the scanner adds the "ADD_Airport" string in the second and third lines. in the main method, I have it so that if(command.equals("ADD_Airport"), it will activate the method. The first line works as I want it to but the rest does not. Thanks

p.s does anyone know where I can practice or find examples of things close to this? thanks.

This is the input file

6 9

ADD_Airline SV Saudia SA saudia.com

ADD-_Airline EK Emirates UE emirates.com

ADD_Airline NS NasAir SA flynas.com

ADD_Airline BA BritishAirways UK britishairways.com

ADD_Airline KL Holland NL klm.com

ADD_Airline GF GulfAir BH gulfair.com

ADD_Airport JED Jeddah KAIA

ADD_Airport MED Madina PMIA

ADD_Airport DXB Dubai DIA

ADD_Airport BAH Bahrain BIA

ADD_Airport CAI Cairo CIA

ADD_Airport LHR London HAL

ADD_Airport AMS Amsterdam AAS

ADD_Airport KRT Khartoum KIA

ADD_Airport CGK Jakarta SIA

//MY CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // input files
    File inputD = new File("inputDB.txt");

    File inputB = new File("inputBookings.txt");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputD);
    // print writer
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("printLog.txt");

    // inputDB arrays
    // airline info
    String[] airlines = new String[sc.nextInt()];
    String[] codes = new String[airlines.length];
    String[] country = new String[airlines.length];
    String[] website = new String[airlines.length];

    // airport info
    String[] airports = new String[sc.nextInt()];
    String[] threeLetter = new String[airports.length];
    String[] city = new String[airports.length];

    String[] flights = new String[sc.nextInt()];

    String command = null;

    out.println("--------------- Air Ticket Reservation System Log ---------------\n");
    do {
        command = sc.next();
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD_airline")) {
            add_airline(airlines, sc, out, codes, country, website)
public static void add_airline(String[] airlines, Scanner sc, PrintWriter out, String[] codes, String[] country,
        String[] website) {

    for (int i = 0; i < airlines.length; i++) {

        

        codes[i] = sc.next();
        airlines[i] = sc.next();
        country[i] = sc.next();
        website[i] = sc.next();

        out.println("(New Airline Added) " + "Airline No.: " + codes[i] + " Airline: " + airlines[i] + " Hub: "
                + country[i] + " URL: " + website[i]);
        out.println("-------------------\n");
        
    }

}
```

It should look like this:

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: SV Airline: Saudia Hub: SA URL: saudia.com

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: EK Airline: Emirates   Hub: UE URL: emirates.com

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: NS Airline: NasAir Hub: SA URL: flynas.com

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: BA Airline: BritishAirways Hub: UK URL: britishairways.com

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: KL Airline: Holland    Hub: NL URL: klm.com

(New Airline Added) Airline No.: GF Airline: GulfAir    Hub: BH URL: gulfair.com

Comment: please share your main method from which add_airline method called also.

Comment: Can we see the input file? The *scanner* isn't adding anything. Likely you are reading a command "ADD_Airport" from the input file into one of your fields.

Comment: I have added the input file and the main method. Yes im reading a command.

Comment: What do you try to do here `String[] airlines = new String[sc.nextInt()];` and use it here `airlines.length`? This seems not like what you intend to do i guess? Have a look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

Comment: Because that means that there is going to be 6 airlines

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code should do something like this:

```
for each line from inputFile:
   split (by ' ') that line into array of parts
   if part 0 == 'ADD_Airline' then
      call `addAirline` method and pass parts 1,2,3,4 to it as parameters
   else if part 0 == 'ADD_Airport' then
      call `addAirport` method and pass parts 1,2,3 to it as parameters
```

Comment: What i want it to do is read the line and if the string at index[0] is ADD_airport or ADD_airline, it should skip over that certain string.

Comment: If you are in a loop, there's `continue` operator in Java that skips current iteration.